# how to add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on google earth server that run on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, google-earth, cesiumjs

i run google earth on ubuntu ( that exist on some virtual machine ).
when i try to get some map on chrome i receive this map.

But when i get 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' exception.

How to define the allow of Access-Control-Allow-Origin ? 
I understand i need to do it on the server side - but i can't find how to do it

And help please

Comment: That's an HTTP header, part of what's called "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing."  Have a look at https://enable-cors.org/

Comment: @emackey :: yes, try everything .. unfortunately nothing work :(

Comment: Check the browser's Developer Tools section for a network tab, and see what URL and which server it's failing to access.